# Why does Implicit Fails when Extended Class is Generic in Scala?

Tags: generics, scala, implicit-conversion

Why does the following code works:

```
class X

class A(implicit c: X)
class B(arg: Int)(implicit c: X) extends A
class C(arg: Int)(implicit c: X) extends B(arg)
```

But not this one:

```
class X

class A(implicit c: X)
class B[T](arg: T)(implicit c: X) extends A
class C(arg: Int)(implicit c: X) extends B(arg)
```

Which fails with the following error:

> error: could not find implicit value for parameter c: core.X
>
> class C(arg: Int)(implicit c: X) extends B(arg)

Comment: -1. It is not helpful when you omit error messages.

Comment: @Antoras you're right... fixed.

Comment: Both work for me on 2.9.1.final.  Which version are you using?

Comment: @RexKerr ➜  ecaalyx-gateway git:(logic) scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.9.1.final -- Copyright 2002-2011, LAMP/EPFL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to work if you help the type inferencer when calling the constructor for `B`:

```
class X

class A(implicit c: X)
class B[T](arg: T)(implicit c: X) extends A
class C(arg: Int)(implicit c: X) extends B[Int](arg)
```

So it doesn't look like a fundamental limitation. But the error message which you didn't include is very unhelpful *could not find implicit value for parameter c: X*.